# multiply arraylist value in java

Tags: java

I enter a number like 1234. I need even position value and odd position value and i have store in arraylist like even position arraylist values are 2 and 4 .In oddd arraylist values are 1 and 3 its all are working fine .But when i multiply arraylist value of 2 and 4 i get 2600 . Please Help

```
import java.util.*;
public class list {


public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Character> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Character> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.print("Enter Distance ");
        String no = sc.next();
        for(int i = 0 ; i < no.length() ; i++){
            if(i % 2 != 0){
                list1.add(no.charAt(i));
            }else{
                list2.add(no.charAt(i));
            }
        }

          for (char c : list1 ) {
            System.out.println(c);
          }

        int tot = 1;
        for (int i=0; i < list1.size() ; i++ ) {
            tot = tot * list1.get(i);
        }

        System.out.print(tot);


    }
}
```

Comment: Your `List<Character>`is a list of characters, but you seem to want to use them as integers.

Answer (score 2):

You are multiplying characters instead of number, which is why you are getting 2600. Cast your character to number before multiplying them. Here is an updated code.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();//changed here
        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();//changed here
        System.out.print("Enter Distance ");
        String no = sc.next();

        try{
            Integer.parseInt(no);
        }catch(Exception e ) {
            System.out.println("NumberFormatException");
            return;
        }

        for(int i = 0 ; i < no.length() ; i++){
            if(i % 2 != 0){
                list1.add(Character.getNumericValue(no.charAt(i)));//changed here
            }else{
                list2.add(Character.getNumericValue(no.charAt(i)));//changed here
            }
        }

          for (int c : list1 ) {
            System.out.println(c);
          }

        int tot = 1;
        for (int i=0; i < list1.size() ; i++ ) {
            tot = tot * list1.get(i);
        }

        System.out.print(tot);
    }
}
```

Comment: its giving errror

Comment: error: no suitable method found for add(int)
                        list1.add(Character.getNumericValue(no.charAt(i)));
                             ^
    method Collection.add(Character) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Character)
    method List.add(Character) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; int cannot be converted to Character)

Comment: Did you change the List type to Integer at around line 6 as suggested by me. `List<Integer>`

Answer (score 1):

You are multiplying `Character`s wih `int`. So characters are automatically cast in integer, but java get the ASCII value of these characters (ex. '0' == 48). Because ASCII value of '2' is 50 as integer and the value of '4' is 52 as integer, you get 2600 when you multiply them.

You could simply convert the ASCII value in integer value by substacting the '0' value:

```
tot = tot * (list1.get(i) - '0');
```

You could use the java 8 stream API to do what you want:

```
int tot = no.chars() // Transform the no String into IntStream
        .map(Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf((char) i))) // Transform the letter ASCII value into integer
        .filter(i -> i % 2 == 0) // remove all odd number
        .peek(System.out::println) // print remaining elements
        .reduce(1, (i, j) -> i * j); // multiply all element of the list (with the first value of 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the character to integer value :

```
for (int i=0; i < list1.size() ; i++ ) {
  tot = tot *  Integer.valueOf(list1.get(i).toString());
}
```